# Why was it made possible from JDK 8 that a local inner class (inside a method) can access the non-final local variables of the enclosing method?

Tags: java, methods, local, inner-classes, final

```
class Outer
{
    public void method1()
    {
        int x = 10;
        class Inner
        {
            public void inMethod()
            {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
        Inner i  = new Inner();
        i.inMethod();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Outer obj = new Outer();
        obj.method1();
    } 
}
```

I have gone through a few questions on StackOverflow, even those didn't have precise answers.
[Method local inner class - can access non final local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705814/method-local-inner-class-can-access-non-final-local-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `x` is not marked as final but it is `effectively-final`.
If you add `x += 5;` below `int x = 10;` it will not longer work, because the variable is not effectively final anymore.
https://www.baeldung.com/java-effectively-final

I guess this was mainly changed/implemented that way to better support lambdas. Imagine you would have to always mark a variable `final` if you wanted to use it inside a lambda.